# How to show/hide labels according to zoom levels with expressions in mapbox-gl-js / maplibre-gl?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, maplibre-gl

I have a point layer with an icon, and I would like to display the labels in addition to the icon only from a certain zoom level (9). I would like to avoid creating a dedicated label layer. Looking at the expression documentation, [Stet](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/#step) and [Zoom](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/#zoom) should give me the desired result, but it doesn't work.

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40156732/7105916), I try to change the size of the text depending on the zoom level, but no matter the zoom, the text will always have the default size (here 7)
Am I missing something or is it a bug? I'm using Maplibre

```
layout: {
          "icon-image": "border_crossing",
          "icon-size": 0.5,
          "icon-allow-overlap": true,
          'text-field': ['get', 'loc_type'],
          'text-variable-anchor': ['top'],
          'text-radial-offset': 0.5,
          'text-justify': 'auto',
          "text-size": [ "step", 
              ["zoom"], 
              0,0,
              9,15,
              7
            ]
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

There are various ways. One would be:

```
'text-field`: ["step", ["zoom"], "", 9, ["get", "loc_type"]]
```

It looks like you had a bug in your `step` code.

Comment: Ok, I had misunderstood how the step function works, it's quite simple actually. Thanks for your answer, it helped me to understand better where my mistake came from!
I kept the text management in the "text-size" key because I find it clearer, this solution works:


`"text-size": [ "step", 
            ["zoom"], 
            0,9,
            15
          ]`